# dynamic HTML with worklight?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there any way to perform "last minute" substitutions in the HTML (or other) resources that are part of your worklight application?

For example, I want to set the `lang` and `dir` attribute on the `<html>` element based on the end-user's locale.

some background:

I realize I can do dynamic DOM manipulation, but my question comes more from a background of client-server architecture where you have an opportunity on the server-side to replace some variables etc. in your HTML (or other resources) based on the requester's context.  We have an existing app already and I'm investigating what it would take to integrate it with worklight including (for performance reasons) moving files from the server-side to the client-side without incurring too much refactoring of the current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update:* per the edit to your question, I don't think the below will make any significant impact on your app. Since you say you may move files from the server to client, this means like network traffic and with today's devices I suspect this may even be a boost to the performance rather than a penalty.

My suggestion is to try the below if the above is what you're planning to do.

I'm not even sure how else would you even do that from the server - change the *application's* UI based on the user's device local's, from the server. Doesn't make much sense to me to do that remotely.

---

To answer your question, I'll provide some background information that is relevant, I think, to a good user experience in this kind of scenario (as I see it):

By default, Worklight dismisses the splash screen once the framework has finished loading.

However, if you're using Worklight 6.2 then you can use the extended Splash Screen feature to display the splash screen for a longer duration, and during that time you could perform the required tasks -- like altering the UI based on the user's locale. Once you're done, you can then programmatically dismiss the splash screen on your own.

Reading materials:

- [Common UI Controls](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/05_02_Common_UI_Controls.pdf) training module (slide #29)
- [Managing the splash screen](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_splash_screen.html) user documentation topic (for both JS and Native support)

Example:

1. You need to uncomment the following in common\js\initOptions.js:

   ```
   // # To disable automatic hiding of the splash screen uncomment this property and use WL.App.hideSplashScreen() API
   //autoHideSplash: false,
   ```
2. You can then dismiss the splash screen when ready:

   ```
   function wlCommonInit() {
       function changeUiBasedOnLocale();
       ...
       ...
   }

   function changeUiBasedOnLocale() {
       ... // get device local
       ... // use JS to alter CSS
       WL.App.hideSplashScreen();
   }
   ```

Comment: BTW, instead of ""rl intern-at-ibm" you should probably just mention the name, per IBM's social guidelines. ;)

Comment: thanks Idar.  Will keep the splash screen in mind. Will change my display name in a month when stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: The name is Idan. I've edited the questions based on your edit to the question.

Comment: Apologies, Idan.  When I say "move", I mean that I would include my resources (html, js, css) as assets bundled with the native app rather than having them fetched and served-up by the server of the network. Surely this is desirable trait in a native app?  In general, my question stems from a paradigm shift. I'm trying to wrap my head around the idea that the assets (html, css, js) that you bundle with your native app, are essentially static.  That is, you have no opportunity to programatically manipulate them before they get displayed in the embedded browser.

Comment: But you can, using JavaScript magic. You include in it all relevant code, and based on the scenario, invoke the relevant code block...

Comment: Yes, I completely understand that once I have resources loaded into the embedded browser that I can do any programatic manipulation that I like using JavaScript, but that is not the essence of my original question.  I'm looking for any hooks that allow me to programatically swap in a few variables **before** my resources get to the embedded browser.

Comment: But you want to have that swapping happen on the server-side, while the app is running and have that content - which resides locally on the device - replaced with the content from the server. This mixing is just bad. You could cheat and say, have the ENTIRE content on the SERVER, and then you can simply load a different EXTERNAL resource altogether (this would be a combination of my above solution + the Include External Resources sample project that displays a webview ontop of the existing one and loads a URL in it). But then you're kinda missing the point of running an app.

Comment: Anyway, Worklight does not provide any such hooks or API. It's either you're running locally or you're running on the server, not dynamically. Even Direct Update would not work as efficiently here. Also think of a situation where the user does not have Internet connection... it's just a recipe for bad user experience and need to handle a growing number of scenarios.

Comment: I'll take this as a "no".   That is, there is no "hook" to do last minute manipulation of local files immediately before the embedded browser loads/displays them. To be clear, I'm not suggesting that this manipulation be done on the server-side. I'm assuming that any code that needs to perform manipulation would be ported to the client-side ... but maybe after doing that work, it may be just as easy to modify our html/js to be even more dynamic; however, in our case, I don't think so.

Comment: The files are locally stored in the app > the app loads > a splash screen is displayed until the framework is ready > the splash screen is gone > index.html is displayed. As I have suggested: you can extend the duration of the splash to as long as you'd like, during which you will perform your modifications "behind the scenes" and remove the splash when you're ready. Remember, what you want to do will take a split of a second. This is what I call a hook to do "last minute manipulation". Why don't you just try it and see if it creates the experience you want your users to have?

Answer (score 0):

Any basic DOM manipulation will help. Here is one example with D3.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            d3.select("html").attr("lang","en_EN");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: True, but in the context of an application you'll want to create a good user experience. For this, see my own answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks, will use DOM manipulation if I **have to**. I added some background/context for my question above.